# Excel matching cell values into comments

Tags: excel, vba

I want my excel automatically convert the matching cell values into comments. In a sheet1, I have set of mobile brand names in first row "A1" to "L1" and in sheet 2 the first column A has the same set of mobile brand name, but the value is repeated in the same column  and in column B the name of the customer who purchases the mobile is noted.

If the cell values of the mobile brand name matches in both the sheets. Then it should retrieve the customer name in sheet2, column B and convert it to comments in the first row of  "A1" to "L1". Kindly anyone let me know any possible code.

This code is helps me to add comments in the first row if sheet1 but i need the exact value in column B which has matching cell value.

```
Sub test()
    Dim rngDB As Range, rngComent As Range
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim cm As Comment, i as integer
    Set rngComent = Sheets(1).Range("a1:l1")
    Set rngDB = Sheets(2).Range("b1:b20")

    For Each rng In rngComent
        i = i + 1
        If Not rng.Comment Is Nothing Then
            rng.Comment.Delete
        End If
        Set cm = rng.AddComment
        With cm
            .Visible = False
            .Text Text:=rngDB(i).Value
        End With
    Next rng
```

Comment: I forgot to add code now i edited that

Comment: Have a look at the [WorksheetFunction.VLookup method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheetfunction.vlookup) which you can use to lookup a value in another table to get your desired value. • If that doesn't help please provide sample data or screenshots of your 2 sheets.

Comment: Its throwing error could you please guide me

Comment: Actually you need to [edit] your question and show the code you have tried and tell which error message you get and in which line. We can only assist you to solve your problem if you show what you have done so far.

Comment: Private sub worksheet_Follow hyperlink(ByVal Target As Hyperlink) 
If Target. Range. Address="$G$13" Then
Dim cAs Excel.range
Set xlsheet=Worksheets("Sheet2")
On Error Resume Next
For Each c In range("A1:L1")
With c
If c=xlsheet. Range("A2:A14) Then
. AddComment
. Comment. Visible=False
. Comment. Text Text:=Worksheet Function.vlookup (c.Value,xlsheet.range("A2:A14"),2,false).value
.comment.shape.TextFrame.Autosize=false
End if
End with
Next
End if
End sub

Comment: Please don't put code into comments. As you can see it is not readable at all. Intead [edit] your original question add it there and format it nicely.

Comment: I am unable to edit, this is the code i am working with but its not populating the cell value its just adding the comment